# Solution Wheels, Escape Game Wheels

Tags: escape-the-room

I was recently playing various exit/escape board games, and was wondering if there is a proper name for the "solution wheels"?

Also, are there any common strategies, techniques or applications to create these?

Examples-Pictures:
[Escape the Room - Mystery at Stargazer’s Manor](https://images.app.goo.gl/XgRsX7ZagNVo6C9P7)
[Exit: The Game - The Secret Lab](https://images.app.goo.gl/Wg3Uqmi4hSR25iNH7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper name for this sort of encoder/decoder ring is a [Cipher disk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipher_disk), but they are also commonly called Caesar or Cipher Wheels.

Generally speaking they are relatively easy to create using either a [ruler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruler), [compass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compass_(drawing_tool)) and [protractor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protractor), or a [template](http://www.mountainvistasoft.com/chaocipher/BuildCipherDisk/).